# R: Can't transform a table into a data frame

Tags: r, rating

I have been using the R package "Player Rating" and I have worked the examples, however when I try to export the output (the rating tables) to a CSV I get the following message:

> write.csv(sobj, file = "output.csv")
>   Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
>     cannot coerce class ""rating"" to a data.frame

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PlayerRatings/PlayerRatings.pdf

Comment: You title seems leading us in the wrong direction, you mention that you can't transforme (import) a table into a R data frame, though in the body of your question you talk about writting object (a data frame as far as I can tell) to a file which involve exportation and means that you already have your table into a data frame...

Comment: Can you give a bit more information on the object that you are trying to write out - perhaps use an example from the package so we can see some code? Thanks

Comment: Using the example from `?elo` ... i suspect you need to use `robj$ratings`

Answer (score 1):

You can only export data.frame/matrix etc using write.csv . The object robj(in your code 'sobj') that you are trying to export is a list. Inside it , it has data.frame "ratings" do as said by @user20650

```
 write.csv(robj$ratings, file = "output.csv")
```